# Add textfield searchbox to header/navbar in Apache Isis

Tags: isis

I'm trying to work out how to add textfield to the navbar in the header that I can use as an always present search box but I haven't had much success. From the documentation ([7.2. Replacing page elements](https://isis.apache.org/guides/ugvw.html#_ugvw_extending_replacing-page-elements)) I see that I can replace components inside a page but I don't think this applies to the header. Can any one point me in the right direction with where to start with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to change the complete header by using [ComponentType.HEADER](https://github.com/apache/isis/blob/e0e55852607612ac2cf32d3c7d7adb17e6c8927d/core/viewer-wicket-ui/src/main/java/org/apache/isis/viewer/wicket/ui/pages/PageAbstract.java#L224-L227).

Setup your own ComponentFactory that will have higher priority than the default one.

Comment: Thanks @martin-g, I've pretty much done this but I'm still seeing the default header. Is there something you have to do to set the priority?

Comment: I think I've worked it out, seem that in the registrar if I do replace rather than add it seems to work:
`//        componentFactories.add(new CustomHeaderFactory());
        componentFactories.replace(HeaderPanelFactory.class, new CustomHeaderFactory());
`

Comment: I believe there is a bug in Isis JIRA for this. I remember hitting the same problem when I worked on this. Glad that you make it work!